# XIB backed View with Subclassing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableViewCell defined in a XIB (with outlets setup) and the custom class set to 'CustomTableViewCell'. I'm now looking to subclass the 'CustomTableViewCell' with a 'SubclassCustomTableViewCell', however I'd like to use the same XIB (and not need to redefine my view. Is this possible? I currently have:

```
+ (SubclassCustomTableViewCell *)create
{
    // Create undefined cell.
    id cell = nil;

    // Iterate over NIB and find a matching class.
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSArray *cells = [bundle loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (cell in cells) if ([cell isKindOfClass:[self class]]) break;

    // Return cell.
    return cell;
}
```

But I can't figure out to to get it to return anything but the parent.

Answer (score -1):

```
+ (SubclassCustomTableViewCell *)create
{
    // Create undefined cell.
    id cell = nil;

    // Iterate over NIB and find a matching class.
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSArray *cells = [bundle loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (cell in cells) if ([cell isKindOfClass:[self class]]) return cell; //change this

    // Return cell.
    return nil; //change this
}
```

could you tell me where `+ (SubclassCustomTableViewCell *)create` is defined, in which class

Comment: It is defined in the subclass. I'm not sure how changing the call to potentially return nil is supposed to help... I do want it to return a table view cell...

Comment: yeah that will not help..but it will return either custom cell or nil... it won't return the parent cell. I have added `return cell;` in for loop. and please put all ur classes

Comment: But the XIB file has the parent cell set as the class. If this is run in the child it will never return anything...